# Scrapy - Change intervals between logging stats

Tags: scrapy

Scrapy is logging it's stats about number of crawled pages, crawling speed etc. once every 60 seconds. Is there a way to change these intervals?

```
2016-12-19 15:09:01 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-12-19 15:10:01 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 82 pages (at 82 pages/min), scraped 28290 items (at 28290 items/min)
2016-12-19 15:11:01 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 167 pages (at 85 pages/min), scraped 57615 items (at 29325 items/min)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an (undocumented?) setting called [`LOGSTATS_INTERVAL`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ed1e4d8df33e53de1516cb025dc60cca9615f637/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py#L198), which defaults to `60` (seconds).
You can change that the interval (in seconds) that you prefer in your `settings.py`. E.g.

```
LOGSTATS_INTERVAL = 5 * 60.0    # log stats every 5 minutes
```